# How to group same record into multiple groups using mongodb aggregate pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a two collections.

**OrgStructure (visualise this as a tree structure)**

Example Document:

```json
{
    "id": "org1",
    "nodes": [
        {
            "nodeId": "root",
            "childNodes": ["child1"]
        },
        {
            "nodeId": "child1",
            "childNodes": ["child2"]
        },
        {
            "nodeId": "child2",
            "childNodes": []
        }
    ]
}
```

**Activity**

Example Document:

```json
[
    {
        "id":"A1",
        "orgUnit": "root"
    },
    {
        "id":"A2",
        "orgUnit": "child1"
    },
    {
        "id":"A3",
        "orgUnit": "child2"
    }
]
```

Now my expectation is to group activities by `orgUnit` such a way that by considering the child nodes as well.

Here i don't want to do a lookup and i need to consider one OrgStructure document as an input, so that i can construct some condition using the document such a way that the query will return the below result.

**Expected result**

```json
[
    {
        "_id": "root",
        "activities": ["A1","A2","A3"]
    },
    {
        "_id": "child1",
        "activities": ["A2","A3"]
    },
    {
        "_id": "child2",
        "activities": ["A3"]
    }
]
```

So im ecpecting an aggregate query something like this

```
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$switch": {
                "branches": [
                    {
                        "case": {"$in": ["$orgUnit",["root","child1","child2"]]},
                        "then": "root"
                    },
                    {
                        "case": {"$in": ["$orgUnit",["child1","child2"]]},
                        "then": "child1"
                    },
                    {
                        "case": {"$in": ["$orgUnit",["child2"]]},
                        "then": "child2"
                    }
                ],
                "default": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You will need 2 steps:

1. create another collection `nodes` for recursive lookup. The original `OrgStructure` is hard to perform `$graphLookup`

```js
db.OrgStructure.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$nodes"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$nodes"
    }
  },
  {
    $out: "nodes"
  }
])
```

2. Perform `$graphLookup` on `nodes` collection to get all child nodes. Perform `$lookup` to `Activity` and do some wrangling.

```js
db.nodes.aggregate([
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "nodes",
      "startWith": "$nodeId",
      "connectFromField": "childNodes",
      "connectToField": "nodeId",
      "as": "nodesLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Activity",
      "let": {
        nodeId: "$nodesLookup.nodeId"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$orgUnit",
                "$$nodeId"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$id"
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "activity"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$nodeId",
      activities: "$activity._id"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jb0IOJz0RJ-) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for the aswer. Just one clarification. Is this performance effective if we are performing this against huge number of records (activities)? @ray

Comment: @Jeevanantham I have updated the answer to include some minor tweaks. You can see a subpipeline is used to group the activity to minimize the intermediate result set. AFAIK, `$graphLookup` is expensive, but it's unavoidable as you are working on recursive dataset. You can probably improve performance by indexing lookup fields used in query 2(i.e. nodes.nodeId, Activity.orgUnit). However, I think the most significant improvement to performance will come from refactoring your schema. Try to re-design with a non-recursive schema and it should make the query easier and more performant.

Comment: Now another use case. Consider i'm only having Activities collection alone and i need to groupby using some kind of condition(for example. $switch) to achieve the same result since i have the OrgStructure document as an input. Is it possible? @ray

Comment: Please don't ask another question in comments. Instead, ask a new question and link to this question to provide context and details.

Comment: i have updated my question as per the above comment @ray

Comment: @Jeevanantham I am not sure if there exists some way to do this. To retrieve all the child node, you still need to traverse the OrgStrucutre document recursively. To avoid the recusrion. I think the only way is refactoring the OrgStructure document to store all childs(e.g. root should store all child1 and child 2 directly)